# How to display value from prestashop module in template

Tags: php, templates, module, prestashop

How can I display my variable in my prestashop template page in a `div` because now it stays at the top of the page.

```
public function hookDisplayCustomerAccount()
{
   global $smarty;
   $userid = $this->context->customer->id;
   $sql = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders  WHERE id_customer = '$userid' AND current_state = '1' ";
   $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
   $custdata=array();
   $sum = 0;
   foreach ($result as $row)
   {
       /*  $custdata[] = array(
           "id_order" => round( $row['SUM(total_paid)'] ,2),
       );*/
       echo round( $row['SUM(total_paid)'] ,2);
    }
    //$this->context->smarty->assign("custdata", $custdata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling the hook at the desired place in your template page like this

`{hook h='displayCustomerAccount' mod='yourmodulename'}`

PS : You may exclude the 'mod' if you have only this module hooked on displayCustomerAccount.

Cheers :)